# ¿Cómo mostrar una variable(string) en mi HTML despues de hacerle un .replace en mi TypeScript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Lo que quiero que haga la web, es que reciba una String en un placeholder, mande esa String por una función para darle formato, y despues devuelva una nueva variable que mostrare en HTML.

El codigo HTML:

```
 <textarea placeholder="pega la lista" [(ngModel)]="listaString"></textarea> 
 <button (click)="convertir(listaString)">Hazme Click</button>
 <label>{{listaSCom}}</label>
```

El codigo TypeScript:

```
public re = new RegExp('\"', "g");

convertir (texto) {
  var listaSCom: String;
  listaSCom = texto.replace(this.re, "'");
  return listaSCom; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues reescribirlo así:

```
<button (click)="convertirListaString()">Hazme Click</button>
```

Y hacer que el método trabaje con las propiedades directamente, no necesitas parámetros si sólo se va a usar con esa propiedad:

```
public re = /"/g;

convertirListaString () {
  this.listaString = this.listaString.replace(this.re,"'");
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, al primer intento no me funciono pegando solo el codigo, pero tras agregar una definición en typeScript de "listaString", funciono perfectamente.

Comment: No trabajo con formularios "de plantilla", siempre con reactivos, así que no estaba seguro cómo estada definido `listaString` en tu componente

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí otra forma de hacer lo que buscaba con mas precisión.

Aquí va el typescript:

```
public re = new RegExp('\', "g"); //Aqui se define la expresion para reemplazar las comillas
public lista: String; /// Esta es la variable que recibimos del HTML
publica lista2: String = "" /// Esta es la variable que regresamos al HTML, con el formato nuevo

convertir(){
      this.lista2 = this.lista.replace(this.re, "'"
}
```

Y aca el HTML:

```
<div class="container>
  <div class=" row">
  <textarea class="col" placeholder="pega la lista" [(ngModel)]="lista"></textarea>
  <button mat-button (click)="convertir(lista)">Hazme Click</button>
  <textarea class="col">{{lista2}}</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

La solución previa hacia lo que esperaba que hiciera, pero, al hacer llamado a la función (en el click) cambiaba el contenido de ambos `textarea`, con la intención de mantener el contenido de la primera ventana sin alterar al generar el de la segunda, se me ocurrió esto.